# Send Verification Email error, where is the problem?

Tags: next.js, content-management-system, nodemailer, payload-cms

I'm new to PayloadCMS and I'm trying to build a new webapp. I arrived at the step where I try to implement email verification, although I'm encountering a strange error I cannot understand... That's why I wanted to ask for your help!
I'm using resend and the custom NodeMailer transport (https://payloadcms.com/docs/email/overview#use-a-custom-nodemailer-transport).
Here is the following setup for email verification I have made :

I observe the following behaviour when the user is created (should I precise user is indeed created):

```
TypeError: req.get is not a function
    at sendVerificationEmail (C:\git\myapp\node_modules\payload\src\auth\sendVerificationEmail.ts:35:36)
    at create (C:\git\myapp\node_modules\payload\src\collections\operations\create.ts:269:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: TypeError: req.get is not a function
    at sendVerificationEmail (C:\git\myapp\node_modules\payload\src\auth\sendVerificationEmail.ts:35:36)
    at create (C:\git\myapp\node_modules\payload\src\collections\operations\create.ts:269:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: TypeError: req.get is not a function
    at sendVerificationEmail (C:\git\myapp\node_modules\payload\src\auth\sendVerificationEmail.ts:35:36)
    at create (C:\git\myapp\node_modules\payload\src\collections\operations\create.ts:269:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

**Expected behaviour:
Email should be sent**

Setup :

Transporter :

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.resend.com',
  secure: true,
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: 'resend',
    pass: process.env.RESEND_API_KEY,
  },
})
```

Payload init:

```
cached.promise = payload.init({
      email: {
        transport: transporter,
        fromAddress: 'mymail@domain.mail',
        fromName: 'MyApp',
      },
      secret: process.env.PAYLOAD_SECRET,
      local: initOptions?.express ? false : true,
      ...(initOptions || {}),
    })
```

User model:

```
const Users: CollectionConfig = {
    slug: "users",
    auth: {
        verify:{
            generateEmailHTML: ({req, token, user}) => {
                // Use the token provided to allow your user to verify their account
                const url = `https://yourfrontend.com/verify?token=${token}`
                return `Hey ${user.email}, verify your email by clicking here: ${url}`
            }
        }
    },
    access: {
        read: () => true,
        create: () => true,
    },
    fields:[
        {
            name: "role",
            defaultValue: "user",
            required: true,

            type: "select",
            options: [
                {label: "Admin", value: "admin"},
                {label: "User", value: "user"}
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "username",
            required: true,
            type: "text"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that's located here? `sendVerificationEmail.ts:35:36`

Comment: @X8inez there is no  own code or a module in my own code called  sendVerificationEmail.ts..it is a module in payload framework in node modules, i changed the version of payload downgraded upgraded , removed node modules installed it again and nothing worked

Comment: Okay! Can you put the code in a sandbox and paste the link here?

Comment: @X8inez i really think it is difficult to reproduce the issue since i am new to most of technologies used in the project, but here is the code in github, you just need to create your own .env file and add these secrets PAYLOAD_SECRET, NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL, MONGODB_URL, you don't need to check all of this code but the backend part only with the page Signup in the frontend

Comment: @X8inez
https://github.com/saher-elgendy/ShopVista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `src/payload.config.ts`, you have mis-typed env variable

```
export default buildConfig({
    // not PUBLICK
    serverURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLICK_SERVER_URL || '',
    ....
})
```

in every else you are correctly using `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL`. this bug might be causing the issue

Comment: oh my?? :)..thanks it works finally

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be a bug. I see the line that calls req.get, it attempts to generate the serverURL if none is provided.

You could set serverURL on your payload config to get around this for now. Opening a bug would be the best way to ensure it gets fixed though!

Comment: i already have set server url in payload config and i got this error

Answer (score 0):

What I found from the code you have written and in the documentation is that you missed an **await** keyword before creating a nodemailer transport. await plays an important role here.

[image]

here is your code

[image]

Comment: it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

[Screenshot of JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nW8k.png) copy code of send verification file and paste it to chat gpt with the problem i am providing you the image it will work great